# Video Streaming Choppy

Tags: video

Since upgrading to Windows 10, video streaming is choppy ( pixelating, fading in and out, etc. ). I have integrated graphics on my MB ( MSI Aspen 7548 ), HP Pavilion a6745f PC. I know it's a old machine, but, it runs Windows 10 fine, otherwise. Any suggestions on how to improve the video issue? Would a dedicated graphics card be a helpful solution? I'm really not too educated on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to give up an old machine because the Video could not keep up. Not entirely uncommon.

Comment: *Would a dedicated graphics card be a helpful solution?* -- It's certainly possible, yes. Discreet cards almost always surpass their integrated counterparts.